# php in side jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have built a count down in jQuery so the count down will go from 5 down to 0  and when it hits 0 it will show an alert. Now i want to show a dynamic image instead of that alert.

So here is my timer / jQuery code

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    (function(){
            var counter = 5;    
            setInterval(function() {
                counter--;
                if (counter >= 0) {
                    span = document.getElementById("count");
                    span.innerHTML = counter;
                }
                // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
                if (counter === 0) {
                    alert('this is where it happens');
                    clearInterval(counter);
                }
            }, 1000);
        })();
}
</script>
```

So now instead of the alert I need it to show:

```
<div style="float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;">
    <div class="skip_btn">
        <a href="<?php echo $long_url2 ;?> ">SKIP AD &gt;&gt;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Where is the `div` you want to show stored? Is it hidden in the page or is an AJAX request required?

Comment: Its in the css of the page.

Comment: how is it no clear ??? I want to inculde a div tag and php inside  the if counter ==0 bit...

Comment: Can you define what you mean by, "dynamic page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this working?

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

(function(){
  var counter = 5;

  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter === 0) {

        alert('this is where it happens');
        document.getElementById( "response" ).innerHTML = "<div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;\"><div class=\"skip_btn\"><a href=\"PHP?\">SKIP AD &gt;&gt;</a></div></div><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
        clearInterval(counter);
    }

  }, 1000);

})();

}
</script>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="response"></div>
```

It`s displayed in response element.
I removed your php code from the link because I had no idea where is it coming from, but you can still use it like this

```
document.getElementById( "response" ).innerHTML = "<div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;\"><div class=\"skip_btn\"><a href=\"<?php echo $url;?>\">SKIP AD &gt;&gt;</a></div></div><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
```

Comment: Yes that works but it shows the link has PHP? So isthere anyway i can change the PHP?  into the <?php echo $long_url2 ;?> ??

Comment: yes, you can. just make sure there is something in $long_url2 and it`s a proper url.